# convert SQL query to LINQ / dot notation

Tags: linq, lambda, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm stuck converting below sql to LINQ query. Basically I just want to group my exam in my table grade then compute for the total number passed, failed, number of times taken and passing rate

```
SELECT testID, 
(SELECT COUNT(testID) FROM tblGrade AS b 
    WHERE b.testID= a.testID AND b.Grade < 80) AS 'Failed',
(SELECT COUNT(testID) FROM tblGrade AS b 
    WHERE b.testID= a.testIDAND b.Grade >= 80) AS 'Passed',
--taken = failed + passed, 
--passingrate = (passed / taken) * 100
FROM dbo.tblGrade AS a
GROUP BY testID
ORDER BY testID
```

EDIT:
My solution below: It works but I think its not the best way, especially the failed and passed property.

```
var xx1 = _unitOfWork.tblGrade.GetAll().GroupBy(a => new { a.testID});
var xx2 = xx1.Select(b => new
           {
             testID= b.Key.testID,
             failed = _unitOfWork.tblGrade.Query(filter: a => a.testID == b.Key.testID).Where(c => c.Grade < 80).Count(),
             passed = _unitOfWork.tblGrade.Query(filter: a => a.testID == b.Key.testID).Where(c => c.Grade >= 80).Count(),
             //taken = failed + passed, 
             //passingrate = (passed / taken) * 100
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks. how can i use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count()` can take a predicate (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`) as argument, so I think you may just do

```
var xx2 = xx1.Select(b => new
           {
             testID= b.Key.testID,
             failed = b.Count(x => x.Grade < 80),
             passed = b.Count(x => x.Grade >=80),
             taken = b.Count()
            })
            .Select(b => new {
               testID = b.TestID,
               failed = b.failed,
               passed = b.passed,
               taken = b.taken,
               passingrate = b.taken == 0 ? 0.0 : ((float)b.passed / b.taken) * 100
            }).ToList();
```

The **query syntax** has the (usefull in this case) `let` keyword, so it might be easier to read

```
var xx2 = from b in xx1
          let failed = b.Count(x => x.Grade < 80)
          let passed = b.Count(x => x.Grade >= 80)
          let taken = failed + passed
          select new {
              testID = b.Key.TextID,
              failed = failed,
              passed = passed,
              taken = taken,
              passingrate = taken == 0 ? 0.0 : ((float)passed / taken) * 100
          }
```

Comment: great answer. but how about the "WHERE b.testID= a.testID" in sql query, will that be in effect using the " b.Count(x => x.Grade < 80)"???

Comment: @samantha07 well the grouping is done. So you're already grouped by testID. The Count will be "by testID"

Comment: @samantha07 I wouldn't have written the "base SQL query" as you did, by the way ;)

Comment: accepted as answer! thank you very much. though wondering why the passingrate is always 0

Comment: why "b.passed / (b.failed + b.passed)" is always zero?

Comment: @samantha07 Remark : I edited my answer. For your question, well, whate are the values of b.passed, b.failed in your cases ?

Comment: Try this to solve the 0 problem: `passingrate = (b.failed + b.passed) == 0 ? 0.0 : (int)((b.passed / (float)(b.failed + b.passed)) * 100.0)`

Comment: @Hogan well that's indeed an integer division problem, but I wouldn't cast the result to an int ;)

Comment: the answer posted by Hogan worked. Thanks. What's your suggestion @raphael? b.taken would result to an error

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - *shrug* typically percentages are not expressed as real values.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
  var h = list.GroupBy(a => a.testID)
            .Select(a => {
               int _failed = a.Count(g => g.Grade < 80);
               int _passed = a.Count(g => g.Grade >= 80);
               int _rate = (int)(_passed / (double)a.Count() * 100.0);

               return new {
                 testID = a.Key,
                 failed = _failed,
                 passed = _passed,
                 taken = a.Count(),
                 rate = _rate,
              };     
            });
```

Full test code:

```
void Main()
{
  List<aGrade> list = new List<aGrade>() {
    new aGrade() { Grade = 40, testID = 1 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 50, testID = 1 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 45, testID = 1 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 70, testID = 1 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 80, testID = 1 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 90, testID = 1 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 40, testID = 2 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 50, testID = 2 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 45, testID = 2 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 70, testID = 2 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 80, testID = 2 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 90, testID = 2 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 40, testID = 3 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 50, testID = 3 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 45, testID = 3 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 70, testID = 3 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 80, testID = 3 },
    new aGrade() { Grade = 90, testID = 3 },
  };    

  var h = list.GroupBy(a => a.testID)
            .Select(a => {
               int _failed = a.Count(g => g.Grade < 80);
               int _passed = a.Count(g => g.Grade >= 80);
               int _rate = (int)(_passed / (double)a.Count() * 100.0);

               return new {
                 testID = a.Key,
                 failed = _failed,
                 passed = _passed,
                 taken = a.Count(),
                 rate = _rate,
              };     
            }); 
  h.Dump(); 
}
// Define other methods and classes here

public class aGrade
{
    public int Grade {  get; set; }
    public int testID { get; set; }
}
```

NB - This code will work as is in LinqPad.  (linqpad.com)  I recommend linqpad for testing this type of code... makes your work, oh so easy.  Try it.